# Break from other class possible?

Tags: java, label, break

I recently rediscovered the use of breaking back to a label. Now I'm wondering if it is possible to break back to a label from another class.

Example of what i want:

#### Main.class

```
label:
for (Product p : ProductList) {
 if (p.getSet() == true) {
  classHandler();
 }
}
```

#### Classhandler.class

```
someFunction() {
 break label;
}
```

While I was typing this I actually tried making a local function in my `Main` class (so I could just call that function instead) but even there I got the `undefined label: label` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. And you shouldn't.

If the condition for breaking is some problem, then throwing an exception would be the correct approach.

Otherwise you should do something like returning a flag that indicates if other products should still be handled and reacting on that in your loop.

As you noticed you can't even `break` through method-borders, and that's a **good** thing. `break` and `continue` are powerful tools, but can *easily* make your code confusing, if used in the wrong way. For example a `break` hidden inside a huge code block can be easy to miss, but if you use a `continue` at the very top of a method to skip an iteration based on some condition, then the intention is pretty clear.

Comment: I guess your right about that, i just tought it would be an elegant way of not doing so much if checks but i'll have to find other ways to deal with that in the future. Thx for all the responses :)

Answer (score 1):

The label that you break to must be in scope.  From the java sun documentation:

> A break statement with label Identifier attempts to transfer control
>   to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same
>   Identifier as its label; this statement, which is called the break
>   target, then immediately completes normally. In this case, the break
>   target need not be a while, do, for, or switch statement. A break
>   statement must refer to a label within the immediately enclosing
>   method or initializer block. **There are no non-local jumps**

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. That does not even work between two methods of the same class. Labels are scoped (at the most) within a single method.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense, since there is no guarantee that label exists, not even that someFunction() is called within a loop.